# How to manipulate Data Transfer Object if sql join 2 tables?

Tags: java, jsp, join, dao, dto

I have a query in **Data Access Object** DAOComments that joins users table and comments table and then store the result into **Data Transfer Object** DTOComments:

```
private static final String SQL_FIND_WITH_USERNAME =
"SELECT u.username, comments.* FROM users u JOIN comments 
ON u.id = comments.id ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 10;";
```

However, DTOComments does not have property "username" since it is  the property of DTOUsers.

**Option 1**

So I decided to use `Map<String, DTOComments>`

In this case the map has `username as KEY, DTOComments as VALUE.`

But this approach will fails, because I care about the ORDER of result and that's why my query returns result in descending order. If I iterate the map on JSP page, the order is not consistent, so my JSP page would output the comment in random order.

(Even if order doesn't matter, I don't know if JSTL can display map's KEY. I know displaying the VALUE though)

**Option 2**

I could put the query result into `ArrayList<DTOComments>`

But I don't see any room to store the `"username"` now. Maybe I can add new property to DTOComments like `private String username;`

hmm... this would violate the concept of having DTO since it **SHOULD** reflect the database table schema.

**Option 3**

Create new class that hold all the information I need (ie. username + properties of DTOComments).

But just because I need one more property "username" in addition to the properties of DTOComments, creating new class seems not right way.

Could anyone give me advice how can I store all info returned by the query above in more organized way?

Comment: It's unclear what ordering exactly you want. The `ORDER BY` is empty. Can you please elaborate? Do you want to `ORDER BY u.username, c.id` or `ORDER BY c.id`? If the former, how do you want to display it in JSP? By comment ID or by username and then comment ID?

Comment: Oops, order by created_date, so I want comment to show up in most recently posted order. I will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I iterate the map on JSP page, the order is not consistent, so my JSP page would output the comment in random order.

That's the nature of `HashMap`. If you want to maintain insertion order in a `Map`, then you should be using [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead. But the `Map<User, Comment>` approach has another disadvantage, if an user has posted more than one comment, you would be overwriting the previously inserted comment this way. You would like to use a `Map<Comment, User>` instead.

But IMHO it's better to make the `User` a property in `Comment` class, indicating a many-to-one relationship:

```
public class Comment {
    private User user; // +getter +setter
}
```

This way you can end up with a `List<Comment>`.

---

That said, I wanted to comment on another statement of you:

> I don't know if JSTL can display map's KEY. I know displaying the VALUE though)

You can iterate over a map using `<c:forEach>`. It goes over [`Map#entrySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29). Each iteration gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) object back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key: ${entry.key}, value: ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I like the latter approach, so are you saying Class Comment which is DTO and add the property that holds DTOUser OR does the example you provided is brand new class?

Comment: No, don't create a new class. Reuse the existing comment and user classes. They have a clearly definied relationship in the database (a foreign key, right?), this should be reflected in the model as well. Additionally, you could also add a `List<Comment>` property in the `User` model. You could make it to be lazily loaded on first getter access. Like as Hibernate/JPA also are doing (aren't you going too far with reinventing? or is it just for hobby/learning purposes? if so, keep it going then :) ).

Comment: Ohh I see, that's good to know that I can add relationship properties to the modal! I'm doing this for learning/hobby but first I want to learn the right way to code/design :) thank you so much for help everytime, I really appreciate your answer in depth!